# Slant right / left canvas text object with Fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to make canvas text object to slant right and slant left using Fabric js ? Screen shots for this.

[For slant right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQpG.png)

[And for slant left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osimK.png)

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on fabric js version you are using, you may have skew support out of the box: (1.6.0-rc+)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var textLeft = new fabric.Text('13-arid-365',{
    left:100,
    top: 25,
    skewX: 45    
});
canvas.add(textLeft);

var textRight = new fabric.Text('13-arid-365',{
    left: 100,
    top: 75,
    skewX: -45    
});
canvas.add(textRight);
```

```html
<script src='http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js'></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Difference between transformMatrix and skew feature is that skew is better supported and allows you to have a coherent bounding box, while transform matrix does not.

Comment: Thank you. I use skew property easily.

Comment: Now can i make text to arc down and arc up in fabric js ?

Comment: And as well as arch up and arch down  using fabric js?